# Prototype of printf and implementation

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I started to wonder how the `printf` function is declared, it always receive a string as first parameter (well, `const char*`) and then the rest of the parameters can be a varierty of types, a variable number of them and given in different order.

Does this mean the `printf` function is declared and overridden for each of the possibilities? This does not make much sense to me, so does it really work like this or it's way different?

Also, how is the function implemented? If it's too complicated I'd just like to know how it works internally in general.

Comment: As a note, `printf` is declared in `stdio.h`, which is an actual file on your system that you can open and look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how the printf function is declared

[printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) and it declared since C99 as follows:

```
​int printf( const char *restrict format, ... );
                                         ^^^
```

The `...` or ellipses indicate that there are a variable number of argument and we would use the *va_start*, *va_arg*, *va_end* macros and *va_list* type to access the arguments.

> how is the function implemented?

and example of a very simple printf is given in the document linked above is as follows and modified to work in *C*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void simple_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == 'd') {
            int i = va_arg(args, int);
            printf( "%d\n", i ) ;
        } else if (*fmt == 'c') {
            int c = va_arg(args, int);
            printf( "%c\n", (char)c ) ;
        } else if (*fmt == 'f') {
            double d = va_arg(args, double);
            printf( "%f\n", d ) ;
        }
        ++fmt;
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    simple_printf("dcff", 3, 'a', 1.999, 42.5); 
}
```

Comment: @YuHao thank you, fixed, cppreference usually has matched C documents, I got confused there.

Comment: Haha, implementing `simple_printf` with `printf` =). I actually wonder if the converting functions that `printf` family uses are accessible, For `scanf` there are things like `ato[fli]` but the reverse ... I could not find it.

Comment: @luk32 it is just to demonstrate how it works, the original C++ example looked a little less silly since it uses `std::cout` but is not really functionally different.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `printf` is:

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

This feature (the argument `...`) is called **variable arguments** functions. You can do it as well with the help of `stdarg.h`.

Here's a start: [C FAQ: Variable-Length Argument Lists](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=varargs)

Answer (score 0):

Each standard library has corresponding header containing the function prototype for all the functions in that library and definitions of various data types and constants that needed by the functions. The header for `printf` is `<stdio.h>` which includes its prototype

```
int printf( const char *restrict format, ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy little program that shows that the prototype for `printf` is:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

(and that it doesn't require the `restrict` keyword as shown by others).

Notice that `printf` here works withOUT including the otherwise-required `stdio.h` header file. This is because simply declaring a *prototype* for the `printf` function keeps the compiler happy by telling it that this function prototype does indeed exist, and since the object code for the definition (implementation) of `printf` also happens to exist elsewhere, the linker is happy at the time of linking, after compilation.

Notice the `extern "C" {}` thing required for C++, however, to prevent the C++ compiler from [name-mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) the function name. See the comments above the code for all compile commands I used and tested. Also note that the printing of the "true" stuff is just for kicks, as I was testing some stuff out.

**hello_world.c**:

```
/*
hello_world

Gabriel Staples
www.ElectricRCAircraftGuy.com
27 Mar. 2019 

Examples of how to compile & run:
- NB: c90 requires C-style comments (slash star, star slash) and does NOT work with modern
      C++-style // comments!
  C:
    gcc -Wall -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    gcc -Wall -std=c90 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    gcc -Wall -std=c11 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
  C++:
    g++ -Wall -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    g++ -Wall -std=c++98 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    g++ -Wall -std=c++03 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
    g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world


*/

// #include <stdio.h>   // for printf
#include <stdbool.h> // for `true` and `false`

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int printf ( const char * format, ... ); // a hacky alternative to including stdio.h above! 
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("`true == 1`? = %i, `true == 1`? = %s\n", true, (true == 1 ? "true" : "false"));

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

> $ gcc -Wall -o hello_world hello_world.c && ./hello_world
>   Hello World
>   `true == 1`? = 1, `true == 1`? = true